# PHP DELETE immediately after select

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-delete

I have a PHP server script that SELECTs some data from a MySQL database.

As soon as I have the result from mysql_query and mysql_fetch_assoc stored in my own local variables, I want to delete the row I just selected.

The problem with this approach is that it seems that PHP has done pass-by-reference to my local variables instead of pass-by-value, and my local variables become undefined after the delete command.

Is there anyway to get around this? Here is my code:

```
    $query="SELECT id, peerID, name FROM names WHERE peer = $userID AND docID = '$docID' AND seqNo = $nid";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result)
        self::logError("FAIL:1 getUsersNamesUpdate() query: ".$query."\n");     

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
        return array();

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $result = array();
    $result["id"] = $row["id"];
    $result["peerID"] = $row["peerID"];
    $result["name"] = $row["name"];

    $query="DELETE FROM names WHERE id = $result[id];";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result)
        self::logError("FAIL:2 getUsersNamesUpdate() query: ".$query."\n");         

    return $result;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are overwriting your `$result` variable with your second statement:

```
$query="DELETE FROM names WHERE id = $result[id];";
$result = mysql_query($query); // result does not contain the array anymore
```

Change the name to something else. It has nothing to do with call-by-reference or such.

---

Actually, your first assignment of the values is unnecessary as `$row` is already an array:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$result = array();
$result["id"] = $row["id"];
$result["peerID"] = $row["peerID"];
$result["name"] = $row["name"];
```

You could just do:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
// at the end
return $row;
```

Then you don't even have to change your variable name for the second statement. But consider to use meaningful variable names.

Comment: I went from what is this guy talking about to OMG I'm an idiot in less than a second. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why not just use only one query to `delete` the row that interests you ?

Something like this should do the trick, I suppose :

```
delete 
from names
where peer = $userID 
  AND docID = '$docID' 
  AND seqNo = $nid
```

*Of course, don't forget to escape/convert the values that should be ;-)*

This way, no need for a `select` query, followed by a `delete` one.

Second : to make your code more easier to read / understand / maintain, you should probably not re-use the same variable for several different purposes.

Here, your `$resul`t variable is used for more than one thing, and it makes things harder to understand :

- resource returned by the first `mysql_query`
- then, array containing data from the first row
- then, resource returned by the second `mysql_query`

It's a bit confusing, and will, one day or another, lead to errors...

**Actually, it already has ;-)** : the third assignment is overriding the data you're getting with the second ones, and boom, you've lost the information that corresponds to the row you've just deleted ;-)

Comment: Thanks, Felix mentioned the problem first. I'm just wondering what you mean about "using only one query to delete the row"? I am using only one query?

Comment: You are using a `select`, and a `delete` : 2 queries. ;;; instead, why not remove the `select` query, and use only 1 query : the `delete` one ? ;;; you'd probably just have to use in the `delete` query the `where` clause that was used in the initial `select` query.

Comment: Oh now I understand what you are saying. I actually need the data that I am about to delete. It will be returned by the server to a client before being deleted forever :)