# How do I remove a row from mysql immediately after calling it?

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

Basically, I have a mysql database where every time I get a row, I want to delete it from the database (after reading its information).

I know I could do something like

```
$result = mysql_query(" SELECT <some row> FROM table ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$id = $row["id"];

mysqli_query(" DELETE FROM table WHERE id=$id");
```

but now it seems I have two queries going on.  Is there a command to tell mysql that I want the row deleted as soon as it gives me the information?  I imagine that'd save time and resources.

In my head, it looks like

```
$result = mysql_query(" SELECT <some row> FROM table THEN DELETE ");
```

EDIT additional information: I wish to use the SELECTed information after deleting the row.  To put it simply, I only want one instance of the information to exist at any give time; it would be as if I were only "moving" a physical copy of the information, so that when it is put on a device/what have you, it is no longer in the table since there is only one copy.

Sorry if my understanding of mysql is rough -- I'm pretty new to it :P

Comment: Do you want to display that SELECT then DELETE or DELETE based on the SELECT result ?

Comment: I think you can create a function.

Comment: Prix, I wish to display the SELECT and then DELETE it.  As a beginner with mysql, I'm not sure if the $result keeps all its information even after the row is deleted, but my intuition from Java says it should.  I know that mysql is much different, though, so I may be wrong.

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706309/php-delete-immediately-after-select) you might get your answer.

Comment: sharif, I've seen that too, and it looked promising, but it sounds like doing the DELETE-ing in one call makes it impossible to get at the information.  I'm referencing the conversation that happens in the comments of Pascal MARTIN's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you need it but you can use a stored procedure for that:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE select_and_delete(IN aid INT)
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = aid;
  DELETE   FROM table1 WHERE id = aid;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee53e/1)** demo.

**`mysql_*` extension is deprecated, therefore use prepared statements and [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).**

Your php code using PDO might look like

```php
$id = 1;

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=UTF8', 'user', 'userpwd');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $query = $db->prepare("CALL select_and_delete(?)");
    $query->execute(array($id));
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Exception: " .$e->getMessage();
    $result = false;
}
$query = null;
$db = null;
//do whatever you need to do with your resultset
var_dump($result);
```

Following a rather simplified table structure (with the only column `id`) presented in SQL Fiddle example if you call it with `$id=1` you'll you'll get in $result:

```php
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for on top of replying to the question also pointing the user the right direction with PDO/MySQLi and dropping mysql_*.

Comment: @user1903064 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: Using timestamp instead is a better way of doing this perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a timestamp field (with default as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) to be able to tell when the row was added.

Then you can run the following MySQL query.

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `timestamp` &gt; DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 SECOND);
```

You will need to run this as a cron job though. AFAIK it can't be done in MySQL alone.